# Attach file from internal storage

Tags: java, android, email, attachment

This question has been asked by many people. I would like to attach a file from internal storage using the below code with accepted comment here on SO:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain-text");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"email@example.com"}); 
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject here");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body text");
            File root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
            File file = new File(root, "myName.csv");
            Toast.makeText(this, file.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           if (!file.exists() || !file.canRead()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Attachment Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
                return;
            }
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send email..."));
```

Permission is used in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The app throws Toast message "Attachment Error".

Comment: What does that -not to the point-message mean?

Comment: @@blackups, the message is: the above code doesn't send attachment.  Without the Uri, the code sends email only (no attachment). The help required is how to fix that so that the above code sends attachment as well. Hope this is clear for you.